Как делать разные действия с разными строками при чтении одного файла в shell?
Я хочу прочитать файл, часть строк я хочу отсортировать, а часть нет, одной командой. Пример:
Есть файл, который содержит header, начинающийся с символа #, его я хочу просто записать в аутпут, а есть строки, не начинающиеся с этого символа, их необходимо отсортировать и записать в тот же файл. Я могу сделать это двумя командами дважды прочитав файл, но если файлы достаточно большие это может быть накладно.
cat input_file | grep "^#" > output_file

cat input_file | grep -v "^#" | sort >> output_file

Вот как можно сделать так чтобы, если строка начинается с #, то она просто записывалась, а если не начинается, то они сортировались?

Построчное чтение и анализ в шелловском скрипте (и даже awk-е) наверняка будет во много раз накладнее, чем 2 чтения grep-ом (даже очень большого (не помещающегося в файловый кэш ядра) файла)

Т.к. символ # находится в таблице ASCII на 4-м месте среди отображаемых символов после пробела, восклицательного знака и кавычек, велика вероятность, что можно обойтись одной командой sort вообще без grep - заголовки автоматически "всплывут" вверх, все остальное будет внизу в отсортированном виде. Это должно сработать если последующие строки не начинаются с пробела, восклицательного знака или кавычек.

А какие могут быть накладки?
В данный момент ты так и делаешь - сперва выбираешь строки, потом сортируешь.
Одной командой оно будет выполняться точно также - выберет строки, потом их отсортирует.
Для отправки в sort ты юзаешь pipe, то есть что две команды, что одна, все хранится в памяти.

@Saboteur ну смысл в том, чтобы не читать файл дважды, а только один раз. У меня же здесь он читается дважды для двух разных команд.

Из файла, данные прочитаются только один раз - память. sort будет получать отфильтрованные данные, набирая их в память, пока не передастся весь файл.
Любая "одна программа" будет делать тоже самое - сперва построчно читает файл и добавляет в память только фильтрованные строки, затем посортирует то, что в памяти.
То есть никакого прироста производительности не будет.
